# Rendering problems of the design window in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, exception, intellij-idea

in Android Studio the Design Window of my Layout file has rendering problems. Even though in the emulator the app works just fine. This is what it says as soon, as i select the design window:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   org.osmdroid.tileprovider.constants.OpenStreetMapTileProviderConstants
>     at
>   org.osmdroid.tileprovider.MapTileProviderArray.getMapTile(MapTileProviderArray.java:93)
>     at
>   org.osmdroid.views.overlay.TilesOverlay$1.handleTile(TilesOverlay.java:182)
>     at org.osmdroid.util.TileLooper.loop(TileLooper.java:34)    at
>   org.osmdroid.views.overlay.TilesOverlay.drawTiles(TilesOverlay.java:161)
>     at
>   org.osmdroid.views.overlay.TilesOverlay.draw(TilesOverlay.java:148)
>     at
>   org.osmdroid.views.overlay.DefaultOverlayManager.onDraw(DefaultOverlayManager.java:107)
>     at org.osmdroid.views.MapView.dispatchDraw(MapView.java:996)    at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:16973)   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3764)    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:61)
>     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)  at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:16973)   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3764)    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:61)
>     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)  at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:16973)   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3764)    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:61)
>     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)  at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:16973)   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3764)    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:61)
>     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)  at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:17070)   at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:387)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:498)
>     at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:434)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:520)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:508)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:967)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:508)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:75)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:620)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:617)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:371)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:617)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:639)
>     at
>   com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$7.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:519)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:337)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:327)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$3.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:271)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:286)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:244)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:234)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
>     at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:352)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

As soon as I hit the refresh button, the error message changes to:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   android.os.storage.StorageManager.getVolumeList(StorageManager.java:922)
>     at
>   android.os.Environment$UserEnvironment.getExternalDirs(Environment.java:87)
>     at
>   android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(Environment.java:404)
>     at
>   org.osmdroid.tileprovider.constants.OpenStreetMapTileProviderConstants.(OpenStreetMapTileProviderConstants.java:24)
>     at
>   org.osmdroid.tileprovider.MapTileProviderArray.getMapTile(MapTileProviderArray.java:93)
>     at
>   org.osmdroid.views.overlay.TilesOverlay$1.handleTile(TilesOverlay.java:182)
>     at org.osmdroid.util.TileLooper.loop(TileLooper.java:34)    at
>   org.osmdroid.views.overlay.TilesOverlay.drawTiles(TilesOverlay.java:161)
>     at
>   org.osmdroid.views.overlay.TilesOverlay.draw(TilesOverlay.java:148)
>     at
>   org.osmdroid.views.overlay.DefaultOverlayManager.onDraw(DefaultOverlayManager.java:107)
>     at org.osmdroid.views.MapView.dispatchDraw(MapView.java:996)    at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:16973)   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3764)    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:61)
>     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)  at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:16973)   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3764)    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:61)
>     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)  at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:16973)   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3764)    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:61)
>     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)  at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:16973)   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3764)    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:61)
>     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)  at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:17070)   at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:387)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:498)
>     at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:434)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:520)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:508)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:967)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:508)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:75)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:620)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:617)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:371)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:617)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:639)
>     at
>   com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$7.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:519)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:337)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:327)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$3.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:271)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:286)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:244)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:234)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
>     at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:352)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

This is my main_activity:

```
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
        import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //important! set your user agent to prevent getting banned from the osm servers
        org.osmdroid.tileprovider.constants.OpenStreetMapTileProviderConstants.setUserAgentValue(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);

        MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
    }
}
```

This is the manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.x.x_x">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name="com.example.x.x_x.MainActivity" >
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

</manifest>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Without showing some code noone will be able to help you finding issues

Comment: yes, i needed to trick the system a bit. It wouldnt let me ask my question, because it looked like spam. Now I edited the code in afterwards. Do you need to see something else?

Answer (score 0):

OSMDroid doesn't provide the information for AndroidStudio/IntelliJ to be able to show the view. What this particular error says is that AndroidStudio is trying to do a preview using a given "tile" from OSRDroid and the tile is not provided yet (because it is done programatically and not by XML).

If you want to see the result, you are going to have to run the app.